# How to get current location using internet in xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gps, currentlocation

how to get current location using internet ?

i'm making an application where i necessary need the latitude and longitude of user.

Would anyone please tell me if i off the iPhone location service from settings and

i want to get current location from internet not from the GPS then how can i get it

in iOS?

is this possible in latest iOS ?

I used the `Core Location framework`.

If any one having any idea please share with me.

Like in `Android` they use something like this

```
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

so i also want to get location if the location service is `OFF`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your location sharing service is off from settings and you will run `CLLocation` it will alert you to turn on that service from settings.

Comment: @iOS.Wolf yes but what if the user doesn't turn on the location service ? i want the user lat long.

Comment: you can't get it from native classes. If you trick it by other then it may be.

Answer (score 0):

there no any apple sdk but you use HTML5. call this html from your native code and get response to handle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```